# Is there a Pandas Function that ignore columns with the same name in an input excel file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have an excel file containing some columns with the same name and want to import it to multiple dataframes before melting data.How can i have the original columns' names in my dataframes. The problem is that i have dataframes with columns named ex:A, A.1, A.2.
For now i am renaming the columns but wan't a better method.

I tried renaming columns but it's too long ( i have more than 30 columns' that are duplicated and renamed more than 10 times) and i want a faster method or a function to do that better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "out-of-the-box" way to do this, you can however remove this suffix with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.str.replace.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'\.\d+$', '', regex=True)
```

Example (with `read_csv`):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('A,B,C,A,B,C\n1,2,3,4,5,6'))
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'\.\d+$', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  A  B  C
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Comment: For reference, [adding a parameter to allow duplicated column names during import was discussed](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47718), but not implemented so far.